# OpenGL ES 2 Shader linking fails when accessing texture using i

Tags: typescript, opengl-es-2.0

I'm trying to add support to multiple shadow maps in my shader and it's just not linking when I try to access a sampler2D inside a uniform struct. My fragment shader:

```c
#version 300 es

precision highp float;
precision highp int;

const int MAX_LIGHTS = 3;

#ifndef LIGHTINFO_STRUCT_H
#define LIGHTINFO_STRUCT_H
struct LightInfo {
    sampler2D shadow_map;
    vec3 reverse_light_direction;
    vec4 color;
    vec3 position;
    float intensity;
    mat4 texture_matrix;
};
#endif

in vec2 vtf_tex_coord;
in vec4 vtf_projected_tex_coords[MAX_LIGHTS];
in vec3 vtf_normal;
in vec3 vtf_frag_pos;

uniform sampler2D u_map_albedo;
uniform sampler2D u_map_normal;

uniform LightInfo u_lights[MAX_LIGHTS];
uniform int u_present_lights;

out vec4 out_color;

const vec4 AMBIENT_LIGHT = 0.1 * vec4(0.8, 0.8, 1, 1);
const float BIAS = -0.006;

float calculateLightIncidence(vec3 position, vec3 lightPosition, float intensity) {
    float d = distance(position, lightPosition);
    return intensity / (1.0 + d * d);
}

bool isInRange(vec2 tex_coord) {
    return tex_coord.x >= 0.0 && tex_coord.x <= 1.0 && tex_coord.y >= 0.0 && tex_coord.y <= 1.0;
}

void main() {
    vec3 testNormal = texture(u_map_normal, vtf_tex_coord).rgb;
    vec3 normal = normalize(vtf_normal);

    float fragmentDirectLight = 0.0;
    float fragmentLightMultiplier = 1.0;

    // calculate for all light sources
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        // if (i >= u_present_lights) break;
        fragmentDirectLight += dot(normal, u_lights[i].reverse_light_direction);

        // shadow map coords
        vec3 projectedShadowMapCoords = vtf_projected_tex_coords[i].xyz / vtf_projected_tex_coords[i].w;
        float projectedCurrentDepth = projectedShadowMapCoords.z + BIAS;
        float projectedDepth = texture(u_lights[i].shadow_map, projectedShadowMapCoords.xy).r;
        float projectedShadowLight = projectedCurrentDepth < projectedDepth ? 1.0 : 0.0;

        float shadowMultiplier = isInRange(projectedShadowMapCoords.xy) ? clamp(projectedShadowLight, 0.3, 1.0) : 1.0;
        fragmentLightMultiplier *= shadowMultiplier;
    }

    fragmentDirectLight = clamp(fragmentDirectLight, 0.1, 1.0);

    float at = calculateLightIncidence(vtf_frag_pos, u_lights[0].position, u_lights[0].intensity);

    vec4 tex_color = texture(u_map_albedo, vtf_tex_coord);
    vec3 col = mix(tex_color.rgb, u_lights[0].color.rgb, at);

    out_color = vec4(col * fragmentLightMultiplier * clamp(fragmentDirectLight, 0.3, 1.0), 1.0);
}
```

Don't mind the messy bit about the color, I'm trying to make the shadow maps work first.

The problem is: If I change the line

```c
float projectedDepth = texture(u_lights[i].shadow_map, projectedShadowMapCoords.xy).r;
```

to

```c
float projectedDepth = texture(u_lights[0].shadow_map, projectedShadowMapCoords.xy).r;
```

It works, everything links and shows correctly. But if I change it back to being index-accessed it doesn't link anymore.

Just to be clear, the link errors are reported in this part of my code:

```js
static createProgram(gl: WebGL2RenderingContext, vertexShader: string, fragmentShader: string): WebGLProgram {
        const program = gl.createProgram();
        if (!program) throw `Failed to create shader program with shaders: ${vertexShader} and ${fragmentShader}`;

        gl.attachShader(program, this.createShader(gl, gl.VERTEX_SHADER, vertexShader));
        gl.attachShader(program, this.createShader(gl, gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER, fragmentShader));
        gl.linkProgram(program);

        const success = gl.getProgramParameter(program, gl.LINK_STATUS);
        if (success)
            return program;

        gl.deleteProgram(program);
        throw `Failed to link shader program with shaders: \n\n${vertexShader}\n\n and \n\n${fragmentShader}\n\nError: ${gl.getError()}`
}
```

And it prints error code 0.

All the uniforms are being set correctly, why does it not link if I change it to access `u_lights[i].shadow_map`?

Also that commented break was because I tried to set the for loop to execute a fixed number of times to see if that was the problem, before it was `for (int i = 0; i < u_present_lights; i++)`.

I get no compilation errors, it just fails to link the shaders.

Here is my vertex shader just in case:

```c
#version 300 es

precision highp float;
precision highp int;

const int MAX_LIGHTS = 3;

#ifndef LIGHTINFO_STRUCT_H
#define LIGHTINFO_STRUCT_H
struct LightInfo {
    sampler2D shadow_map;
    vec3 reverse_light_direction;
    vec4 color;
    vec3 position;
    int casts_shadows;
    float intensity;
    mat4 texture_matrix;
};
#endif

layout (location = 0) in vec3 a_pos;
layout (location = 1) in vec2 a_uv;
layout (location = 2) in vec3 a_normal;

out vec2 vtf_tex_coord;
out vec4 vtf_projected_tex_coords[MAX_LIGHTS];
out vec3 vtf_normal;
out vec3 vtf_frag_pos;

uniform mat4 u_model;
uniform mat4 u_view;
uniform mat4 u_projection;

uniform LightInfo u_lights[MAX_LIGHTS];
uniform int u_present_lights;

void main() {
    vec4 world_pos = u_model * vec4(a_pos, 1.0);
    gl_Position = u_projection * u_view * world_pos;
    vtf_tex_coord = a_uv;

    for (int i = 0; i < u_present_lights; i++) {
        vtf_projected_tex_coords[i] = u_lights[i].texture_matrix * world_pos;
    }
    
    vtf_normal = mat3(u_model) * a_normal;
    vtf_frag_pos = world_pos.xyz / world_pos.w;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OpenGLES 2 uses GLSL ES 100. Appendix A sections 4 and 5 [here (p108)](https://www.khronos.org/files/opengles_shading_language.pdf) cover the rules about indexing samplers. The rules mandate support for `constant index expression`, which basically means you can use a hardcoded/constant index, a uniform or a simple loop. You're using a simple loop so you're satisfying that condition.

But there's something a bit odd. Your title mentions OpenGLES 2, but your shaders specify `#version 300 es` which should only be used on OpenGLES 3 or higher, so I'm not sure quite what the situation is there.

The spec for GLSL ES 300 is [here](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/es/3.0/GLSL_ES_Specification_3.00.pdf) and it has stricter rules for indexing samplers. In ES 300, the rule is `constant integral expressions` only. This rules out using indexes from simple loops as you're doing. Quote from the spec:

> Indexing of arrays of samplers by constant-index-expressions is supported in GLSL ES 1.00. A constant-
> index-expression is an expression formed from constant-expressions and certain loop indices, defined for
> a subset of loop constructs. Should this functionality be included in GLSL ES 3.00?

> RESOLUTION: No. Arrays of samplers may only be indexed by constant-integral-expressions.

You might be stuck with unrolling your loop by hand.